# How to override order of custom tabs in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

With the code below, I am trying to reorder the product tabs to make FEATURES tab appear first. This doesn't take any effect even after running content deploy command.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="product-custom.js" as="product-custom.js" template="Magento_Catalog::product/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <body>
        <!-- Create container for main product tabs -->
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="custom-before-footer-container" before="before-footer-container" label="Luxury Custom - container for main tabs" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-before-footer">
                <container name="custom-before-footer-content" label="Luxury Custom - main tabs content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="content">
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- Hide additional tabs -->
        <referenceBlock name="additional-tabs" display="false" />
        <!-- Move product tabs into new place -->
        <move element="product.info.tabs" destination="custom-before-footer-content" before="-"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.features">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Features</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The picture below shows how the tabs currently appear on the product page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your store use a third party theme? If yes, check its configuration setting for the order of product tabs in Magento admin itself, in the side menu bar.

Comment: Yes, we use Swissup Argento theme. thanks.